# Permission of page for Special Windows Account in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, authentication, permissions

I have report page `report.aspx` in my company. And i want just special windows account can use this report.

For example;

`AA`, `BB`, `CC`, `DD` is our 4 different `Windows Account Name` in our `Active Directory`.

We want to use this report just 4 users. Other users want to access this report page should give an error message. (Like: `You have no permission`)

How can i do that?

Should i write some code in `Page_Load()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be accomplished by modifying the web.config file as is shown in this article [Limit file access to specific users in IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277695/limit-file-access-to-specific-users-in-iis)

EDIT:
You may need to setup the default authorization for the site similar to this:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authentication mode="Windows"/>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?" />
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
    <location path="report.aspx">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="AA,BB,CC,DD" />
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

There are some cases where the order of items in the file does matter so I would put the Location elements after the System.Web element to make sure that it initializes the Authentication/Authorization for the site before it does for specific pages.

Comment: I agree with this approach, you want to avoid hardcoding various Windows accounts in your application. Let the ASP NET runtime worry about that kind of stuff.

Comment: I try it, but when i deny one user for one page, the user can't access all page under same folder. Do i have to use allow and deny both?

Comment: <location path="/Progs/ilis.aspx">
      <system.web>
         <authorization>
            <deny users="user1"/>
         </authorization>
      </system.web>
   </location>

Comment: Do you have any other Authentication/Authorization implemented for your site?